# Android: Change a Button's text in a Dialog

Tags: java, android, button, nullpointerexception, dialog

I have in my Android App a Dialog which contains beside other things a Button. Now I want to change the text of that Button, but I get a NullPointer Exception.

The Button opens up a new Dialog (Datepicker) which gives the MainActivity a date (as a String) which I want then to use for the Button. Obviously I can declare the button and define him, but not interact. Within the try-statement (not sure whether it is a statement) the first line worked, but if I have the second line not commented and call it it crashes (or calls an exception, I added the try part later). I hope this is specific enough.

Here is the code from the button, the MainActivity and the Dialog the button lives in:

Dialog (.java)

```
public class CreateDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstance) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        builder.setView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_create, null))
                .setMessage(R.string.create)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.create, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Dialog (.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id = "@+id/dialog_create"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    android:background="@color/create_bg_1"
    tools:context = ".CreateDialogFragment">

    <EditText
        android:id = "@+id/dialog_create_name"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "@dimen/textFieldHight"
        android:text = "@string/create_name"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "@dimen/textFieldHight"
        android:ems = "6"
        android:text = "@string/date"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id = "@+id/create_date_button"
        android:onClick = "pickDate"
        android:layout_below = "@id/dialog_create_name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity -> Method that is causing the problem and method that calls the dialog (.java - partially)

```
public void openCreate(View view) {
    createDialogFragment = new CreateDialogFragment();
    createDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "TEST");
    updateSelectedButton(3);
}
```

This causes the problem:

```
public void dateForWhatever(int year, int month, int day) {
    DateFormatter dateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
    String date = dateFormatter.toStringDE(year, month, day);

    try {
        Button createDateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_date_button);
        createDateButton.setText(date);
    } catch (Exception cannotFindButton) {
        System.out.println("Geh kacken\n" + year + " " + month + " " + day);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution. I had to save the reference of the Button in a variable in the Dialog (.java) file. Then I just made a getter and could get the Button. Pretty simple actually, so that means, that the MainActivity and the Dialog must have two diefferent lifecycles. I also added these two lines to get the Button's reference:

```
View rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_create, null);
createDateButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.create_date_button);
```

and in addition to work:

```
builder.setView(rootView).set [...] ;
```

If anybody has the same problem and this dicription is not enough, just comment and I will fill it with more detail.

John

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
Button createDateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_date_button);
```

to

```
Button createDateButton = (Button) createDialogFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.create_date_button);
```

Your `create_date_button` is in the `Dialog`'s XML so you need a reference to that to get the `Button`

Comment: that does not work. CreateDialogFragment extends DialogFragment therefor it has no method like findViewById. And I thought findViewById works globally, that is what it is for?! This is the compiler error: Error:(108, 68) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)

Comment: This might work. I saved the reference in the object and that is the way I access it. But thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score -1):

```
     make constructure in CreateDialogFragment class
     String text1,text2;
     public CreateDialogFragment(String btn1Text,String btn2Text
     {
     text1=btn1Text;
     text2=btn2Text;
     }


     in this code change

      builder.setView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_create, null))
            .setMessage(R.string.create)
            .setPositiveButton(text1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(text2, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                {

                }
            });
```

Comment: -1 because no description how your answer can solve op problem. I will upvote it if you add description.

Comment: I do not really understand your answer. And I want to change neither the positiveButton nor the NegativeButton and the Button is definitly chaanged in runtume...